# datatables sorting data with mix numbers and letters

Tags: javascript, sorting, datatables

Updated with jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pnnorhtg/

I have a data table and I am having a difficult time initializing the 'numbers with html' data tables plug-in https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/num-html.

It's initially sorted on 'Count' DESC. However once I execute my function that modifies and appends html to each of the cell in that column it is no longer sortable.

Based on my research this plug-in should be able to fix this but I am having no luck.

This is my data:

```
var preHtmlData = [{
  Brand: "Toyota",
  Count: 33423,
  GBV: 242445
}, {
  Brand: "Ford",
  Count: 23558,
  GBV: 334343
}, {
  Brand: "Honda",
  Count: 9466,
  GBV: 933455
}];
```

This is my function that goes through and adds html text to the value based on the key:

```
//adding text next to Count
function updateItemCount(preHtmlData) {
    for(var key in preHtmlData) {
            var value = preHtmlData[key];
            console.log(value)

     if (value.Brand == 'Toyota') {
            value.Count = value.Count + ' <div style="font-size: 10px;margin-top: -5px">Toyota Purchases</div>';
        } else if (value.Brand == 'Ford') {
            value.Count = value.Count + ' <div style="font-size: 10px;margin-top: -5px">Ford Purchases</div>';
        } else if (value.LOB == 'Honda') {
            value.Count = value.Count + ' <div style="font-size: 10px;margin-top: -5px">Honda Purchases</div>';
        }
        }
    }
```

This is what where I am initializing table:

```
 summary_data_table = $('#resultsTable').DataTable({
        "bSort": true,
        "destory": true,
        "data": data,
        "searching": false,
        "paging": false,
        "order": [
            [aryJSONColTable.length - 1, "desc"]
        ],
        "dom": '<"top">t<"bottom"><"clear">',
        "columnDefs": aryJSONColTable,
                [
                 { type: 'natural-nohtml', targets: 5 }
               ]
        "initComplete": function(settings, json) {
            $("#resultsTable").show();
        }
    });
```

I've added the plug-in and constructed my code as per the documentation, I have a feeling its some how I've defined my columnDefs, but I need it to execute aryJSONColTable and the natural sorting.

Comment: the wrong `"columnDefs": aryJSONColTable,` seems to cause this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE

As seen from your fiddle, you can overcome this problem by placing an order type("type":"natural") inside your custom properties that you pass on to columnDefs

```
customParams = {
  "targets": keys.length - 1,
  "sTitle": "Item Count",
  "type":"natural"
}
```

Please see the updated fiddle for the solution https://jsfiddle.net/pnnorhtg/1/

Comment: thanks for your response, I've tried this and the sorting functionality still isn't working. Should I be initilizing the natural.js plugin before the datatables.js file? or does that order not matter? Right now I'm calling natural.js script after datatables.js, but I've tried both ways.

Comment: Can you produce jsfiddle pls so we can help you better?

Comment: here is a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/pnnorhtg/  Hope this helps. Also if there is another way of doing it besides the natural sorting plugin I'd like to hear about it